# parse foursquare json without 3rd party

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, foursquare, getjson

Im using foursquare API in a web app, and I have the call to foursquare and the results dead on, but I can't parse it out in the way that I want.  I don't want to use a 3rd party parser because those have confused me thoroughly.  I want the app to alert out a list of clickable venue names, by distance, and when clicked a variable is assigned to the lat and lng of that venue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-27.58818,-48.523248&   
   client_id=9&client_secret=9&v=20111107",
    function(data){
//code here
      });
    });
```

The results look like this:

```
    {"meta":
  {"code":200},
 "response":
 {"venues":
 [{"id":"4c158143a1010f47a1364e18",
"name":"Parma Pizza",
 "contact":{"phone":"+554832346363","formattedPhone":"+55 48 3234-6363"},
"location":{"address":"R. Lauro Linhares, 1052",
"lat":-27.588341,
"lng":48.5232834,
 "distance":18,
```

So far ive tried 3rd party Jackson with fail, alerting out names with fail, document.write with fail, and some type of .$each remover which also failed.  Please help I am so stuck.

Comment: In what way did they fail? Have you first confirmed that the callback is running?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is already parsing your JSON file with `$.getJSON`. Unless you're using an old browser you don't need a 3rd party JSON parsing library.  (Although you should include [JSON3.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3) in your code base just in case someone trying to use your site is in an old browser.  Just include it.  You don't need to do anything else other than that.)

The `data` variable being passed into the callback function is a JavaScript object.  You can then just do `data.meta.code` to get the value of `code` (200), or `data.response[0].name` to return `Parma Pizza`.

As for generating your list you're going to have to do the hard work.  You can use `$.each` to iterate though the places easily though:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-27.58818,-48.523248&client_id=9&client_secret=9&v=20111107", function(data){
    $.each(data.response, function(index, elm){
        console.log(elm.name);
    });
});
```

Will print out a list of all the venue names returned from your query.

Comment: This helped!  I can finally get it to echo out Parma Pizza using alert(data.response.venues[0].name)but I can't get the list to work, it doesn't show anything and when I alert out console it just says undefined.

Comment: Actually, I assigned them each a different variable and then echoed them out ala list.  But it won't let me vote up ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ Celeste

I think you can fix it by adding **.venues** in the code from tkone. 
Atleast this worked for me.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-27.58818,-48.523248&client_id=9&client_secret=9&v=20111107", function(data){
$.each(data.response.venues, function(index, elm){
    console.log(elm.name);
});
```

Sorry for not commenting on tkone's answer, but I don't have reputation enough to comment :/ strange system ....